# jquery mobile how to properly load shared header and panel HTML to pages that reside different directories

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-ajax

I am building a multiple page app using jQuery Mobile and use loadPage() to get a different page.

The high-level structure is as below.

- landing.html
- /app-pages/page1.html
- /app-pages/page2.html
- /app-pages/page3.html
- /shared/header.html
- /shared/panel.html
- /images/
- /css/
- /js/core.js

In the core.js, I have JS to load menuPanel.html and header.html to the specified multiple pages. My codes are as below.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role="page"]', function(){ 
$.mobile.activePage.find('#menuPanel').load("shared/menuPanel.html", function(){ 
    $(this).parent().trigger('pagecreate');
});       
$.mobile.activePage.find('#masthead').load("shared/header.html", function(){ 
    $(this).parent().trigger('pagecreate');
});     
});
```

This loading the HTMLs work fine on the landing.html, but once navigated to a different page in the app-pages directory, I see the 404 error in the console and the file path in the error is "app-pages/shared/menuPanel.html" and "app-pages/shared/header.html" The files are found using relative path.

How can I improve the load script that can be globally used so the page can reside in different directories and still work?

How can I also improve the link path in the panelMenu.html? Currently, it's coded using relative path and pointing to app-pages directory which only works on the landing.html.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just put a / (foreward slash) in front of each link to make it relative to the root folder.

Comment: It looks like I can't use the forward slash as the server is Worklight.